# Mediawiki URL for images with special characters

Tags: php, mediawiki

I know that MediaWiki uploads for images are placed in subfolders based on the first two characters of the md5 sum of their file name. This works for the vast majority of the files I have checked, with the exception of files that have "special characters" like diacritics in their names, in which case the plain md5 hash of the name is not correct. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?
echo "Hash prefix should be 11: "; // http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikivoyage/de/1/11/Basel_Straßenbahn-Anhänger_0165-ah.jpg
$name = "Basel_Straßenbahn-Anhänger_0165-ah.jpg";
echo substr(md5(urlencode($name)), 0, 2) . "\n"; // hash is actually 1c!
?>
```

I've tried it both with and without the urlencode call to the name to escape characters. Does anyone know what additional special rules are applied to these names before the hash is run? I poked around in FileRepo.php and related classes, but I couldn't disentangle the logic flow.

Comment: What encoding is this PHP file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first byte of the MD5 sum of that filename is, in fact, 11:

```
sh% echo -n 'Basel_Straßenbahn-Anhänger_0165-ah.jpg' | md5
11cead5cf97b83d366f90d59a19f1f4f
```

If you're getting something different, your PHP file is probably not using the UTF-8 encoding. Try with an ASCII source code representation of the filename:

```
"Basel_Stra\xc3\x9fenbahn-Anh\xc3\xa4nger_0165-ah.jpg"
```

Comment: That put me on the right track: the problem is a single character can have multiple valid UTF8 representations (e.g., "ä" can be (c3 a4) or it can be (61 cc 88)), so I needed to normalize it before hashing, as per http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/convert-between-unicode-normalization-forms-on-the-unix-command-line